# Microservices vs Cost

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, architecture, microservices

We recently moved to micro services but we are facing the debate in the deployment.

Previously, we were having a single docker container and it was not an issue in AWS

since we were running in the single docker container in EC2 instance
But now considering micro services we are in a need to deploy as multiple docker containers in ECS fargate which is not cost effective

Is there anyone come across this scenario and How did you resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

You are not comparing the same things here.

Running a docker container on EC2 and running a docker container on Fargate are two very different things. Fargate is basically running your docker container serverless. This means that your do not need to manage an EC2 instance here.

If you want to compare the same things, I suggest looking into Amazon ECS. This runs multiple docker containers on EC2 machines you still need to manage.

**ECS**, is a simple service, where the control plane is abstracted away by AWS. You simply launch Worker nodes, which consist of EC2 instance with Docker installed, and a Container daemon running which contains the minimum metadata to know to which cluster it belongs to, and to receive instructions from AWS ECS control plane. Thus, with ECS you only pay per Worker node, read EC2 instance.

**Fargate** abstracts from you the hosting platform of containers - the EC2 instances. This obviously means that you pay a premium per container, compared to ECS. So yes, the cost per Container in Fargate will naturally be higher. On the other hand, and to perform a fair comparison with pure ECS, you should also take into consideration maintenance costs associated with ECS. The hours invested troubleshooting, upgrading ECS instance agents, updating EC2 instance packages, etc., is translated in the form of salaries. Thus, should not be forgotten.

**EKS**, being Kubernetes under the hood,  requires Master nodes always running to monitor the cluster, the EKS control plane. This does not come for free, and will cost you minimum pro cluster 0.20 US Dollars/ hour, which amounts to 144$ pro month. This just to start playing around, without any Worker node. From here on, you only pay the normal price for EC2 instances you launch for Worker nodes, just like the ECS offering.

Comment: Sorry I think I confused my query. What I am expecting is, Without MicroServices It runs as single container but with MicroService we run multiple containers so I find running multiple containers is not cost effective

Comment: so How to handle this for multiple MicroServices

Comment: As you can see in my answer, there is no difference in cost if you compare it using the same stuff

Comment: @ThimasVdBerge, There will be cost difference right, Say I have a single container with 6GB for all the services but for microservices, I need to have minimum of 1GB for all the 10 services I have

Comment: @Harry You can run multiple containers on the same EC2 instance. With ECS, for instance.